# UIKit.NSUnderlineStyle single or styleSingle

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I am trying to upgrade my [AttributedTextView](https://github.com/evermeer/AttributedTextView) library to Swift 4.2. 
During this conversion I had to change NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle to NSUnderlineStyle.single and now my project builds and runs

Now I want to publish my update, but when doing a `pod lib lint` I am getting the following error:

```
- ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  /Users/evermeer/Dev/GitHub/AttributedTextView/Sources/Attributer.swift:621:48: error: 'single' has been renamed to 'styleSingle'
- NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  UIKit.NSUnderlineStyle:15:23: note: 'single' was introduced in Swift 4.2
```

when I change it back to styleSingle, the pod error disappears but my project won't build.

My pod spec does contain the line

```
 s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'SWIFT_VERSION' => '4.2' }
```

but setting it to any other version does not help.

any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Use `s.swift_version = '4.2'`. The `pod_target_xcconfig` way is not used to define the Swift version when linting or integrating a pod.

Comment: @dnkoutso Thanks! That solved this warning! I also had a hidden .swift_version file that contained 4.0. Fortunately the warning for that was clear enough. If you could make a answer from this instead of a comment, I could accept your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using the now deprecated pod_target_xcconfig you should use:  `s.swift_version = '4.2'`

In my case I also had a file with the name .swift_version that contained `4.0`

If you use both and they are different, then you will get a warning.